# Viewing CORS success/failure in the Google Cloud logs OPTIONS requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud Storage Buckets allow web access (using `UploadServer`), and allows CORS settings. All HTTP requests show up in the load-balancer logs.  When using CORS, it usually shows as two entries - the `OPTIONS` and the `GET` requests.  If CORS fails, the `UploadServer` still returns 200 for the `OPTIONS` request, but does not return any `access-control-*` headers. Compliant browsers will not make a `GET` request.  Is there a way to track when requests succeeded or failed CORS validation? The logs do not seem to contain any relevant information, except for the missing `GET` request - which might be the result from some other issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "using UploadServer"? Also, what do you mean by tracking? Would you like to filter logs for only those failed requests?

Comment: The "UploadServer" is what Google calls their web server that serves files directly from the buckets.  Every served request shows up in the load balancer log. If request contained CORS-related headers, but response does not, it means server refused CORS, especially with the OPTIONS method.  The logs do not contain this information, making it very hard to debug issues.